# Dropdownlist issue in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

hi all i have a controller

```
  public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
    {
        ....
        var column = new Models.ColumnMapping("CTR");
        ViewData["ColoumName"] = column;
        var search = new Models.Search(columnname,searchvalue);

        return View(search);
    }
```

my view data contains following model property value..

```
public class Column {
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public DataTypes DataType { get; set; }
   }
```

i have to create a drop down list for ColumnName(all data contain in VIewData) and my view is like

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor("clname", ViewData["ColoumName"] as IEnumerable<AML.Web.Models.Column>, "ColumnName", "ColumnName"))
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, This is just an example.

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerNameID, "--Select--")
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult CustomerInfo()
 {
    ViewBag.CustomerNameID = new SelectList(new[]
    {
     new {ID="1",Name="name1"},
     new{ID="2",Name="name2"},
     new{ID="3",Name="name3"},
     },"ID", "Name");
       return View();
 }
```

**Model**

```
public Class ViewModel {
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

If you have to use `@Html.DropDownListFor` then it should like this `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId ,(List<SelectList>)ViewBag.CustomerNameID,"-- Select --", new { @class = "input-block-level" })`

Answer (score 0):

instead of DropDownListFor try DropDownList with SelectList().

```
@Html.DropDownList("clname", 
new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["ColoumName"], "Id", "ColoumName"))
```